# F# extensions used in a context where a function is not expected

Tags: f#

Hi I have an extension method in f# that checks is TcpClinet is connected and it is rather simple code:

```
[<Extension>]
type TcpExtension() =
    [<Extension>]
    static member inline IsConnectionEstablished(client: TcpClient) : bool = 
       let ipProperties : IPGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties()
       let tcpConnection : Option<TcpConnectionInformation> = ipProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections() |> Seq.tryFind(fun connection -> connection.LocalEndPoint.Equals(client.Client.LocalEndPoint) && connection.RemoteEndPoint.Equals(client.Client.RemoteEndPoint))

       match tcpConnection with
         | Some connection -> true
         | None -> false
```

Now I am trying to use it by simple:

```
let private WaitForData (client : TcpClient) = 
    let isConnectionAlive : bool = client.IsConnectionEstablished
    isConnectionAlive
```

But I am getting message that looks like:

> This function takes too many arguments, or is used in a context where a function is not expected

When I checked Microsoft documentation this is how they show it should be handled, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is a bit misleading, you're actually *missing* an argument

To invoke the function you need to pass in `unit` like if you were invoking it from C#

```
let isConnectionAlive : bool = client.IsConnectionEstablished()
```